# Regarding Sujud

Tags: salat, fiqh, imam-al-jamaah

Salamu'alaikum. 
Please is it permissible for someone to spend longer time in Sujud while the Imam had already gotten up? If no, kindly help me with the Hadith that prohibits that.
Jazakumullah Khairan.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 2):

[Sahih al-Bukhari, Narrated `Aisha](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/22/14)

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) during his illness prayed in his house sitting,
>   whereas some people followed him standing, but the Prophet (ﷺ)
>   beckoned them to sit down. On completion of the prayer he said, **"The
>   Imam is to be followed. So, bow when he bows, and raise your head when
>   he raises his head."** (See Hadith No. 657 Vol 1 for taking the
>   verdict).

[Narrated that Abu Hurairah](https://sunnah.com/nasai/11/47)

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'The Imam is appointed to be
>   followed, so when he says the takbir, say the takbir, and when he
>   recites, be silent.'

[Muwatta Malik](https://sunnah.com/malik/3/61)

> .... The imam is appointed to be followed as a leader, so do not oppose
>   him.' Abu Hurayra said, 'The one who raises his head and lowers it
>   before the imam - his forelock is in the hand of a shaytan.

Comment: Jazakumullah Khairan

Answer (score 1):

You must follow the imam as else you may risk that you prayer would be invalid according the opinion of some scholars. Note that imam in Arabic means leader! The imam of a congregation leads the prayer.

The main reference are the ahadith which have been narrated on the authority of Anas ibn Malik (see in Sahih al-Bukahri [1](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/126), [2](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/18/34) [3](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/10/200) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/213)), abu Hurrairah (see in [Sunan ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1308940) and [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/213)), Hittan ibn 'Abdullah ([Sunan an-Nasa-i](https://sunnah.com/nasai/10/54)), 'Aisha (see in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/22/14) and [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/88)) and many more similar ahadith and narrations.

Imam an-Nawawi commented the hadith as follows:
 <sub>This is my own translation take it with the necessary care</sub>

> وفيه وجوب متابعة المأموم لإمامه في التكبير والقيام والقعود والركوع والسجود وأنه يفعلها بعد الإمام
> This hadith shows that the ma'umum is asked (wajib) to follow his imam, in his takbeer, standing, sitting, bowing and prostrating and that he has to do what the imam has done after the imam. (Source fatwa on islamweb #[121568](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/121568)

Note that salat in congregation is a symbol of unity if you prolonged your sujud you would be like a misfit in the jama'a also it may lead you to riya' as you may come to the conclusion that you are more pious than the rest ...

There are ahadith on the opposite situation if a person for example stands up before the imam too.

In this fatwa on islamqa #[33790](https://islamqa.info/en/33790) all the four cases that may happen to a ma'mum in a congregation prayer (Anticipation (doing a movement before the imam), Delay,  Doing an action simultaneously with the imam and Following) are discussed.

Comment: Masha Allah.  Jazakumullah Khairan